# MailMessage .NET with HTML body css doesnt display

Tags: css, outlook, styles, mailmessage

I have this c# code

```
     MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
     message.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailInfo.ToAddress)); 
     message.From = new MailAddress(_settings.EmailFromAddress); 
     message.Subject = mailInfo.Subject;
     message.IsBodyHtml = true;
     message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
     message.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(mailInfo.Body, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html));
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
```

The output HTML is fine, if i open it from browser all styles are fine. But in OutLook dont work. I have try to add it inline but also doesnt work.

For example this works on Brower but not in Outlook.

```
  <div style='background-color: #003F87;color: white;border-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 10px;border-top-width: 0px;border-right-width: 0px;border-left-width: 0px;border-color: #4981CE;font-size: xx-large;padding: 10px;'>
      Spool Tester Report
    </div>
```

Comment: css is very limited in emails - have a google, mailchimp have a good guide on how to write good css and what features you can use in different email clients

Comment: According to https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/border-radius/ border-radius is not supported in Outlook.

Comment: did you get this fixed?